# How do include header files function

Tags: c

Ok, so how I understand `#include` works is by looking up what you are including and complies that and replaces it where the include is. however, when I assume this, my program doesn't compile and it gives *_*_ is undefined all over the place.

for example when in my **main.c** will have something like

```
#include "tim.h"
#include "tim_cfg.h"
#include "tim_api.h"
```

**tim.h** contains  some `typesdef`s like

```
typedef enum
{
RATE_DIV1 = 0X0,
RATE_DIV2 = 0X1,
RATE_DIV3 = 0X2,
RATE_DIV4 = 0X3,
RATE_DIV5 = 0X4,
RATE_DIV6 = 0X5,
RATE_DIV7 = 0X6,
RATE_DIV8 = 0X7,
RATE_DIV9 = 0X8
} BaseRate_T;

typedef unsigned char byte;
```

**tim_cfg.h** contains register locations and basic `struct`s

```
typedef struct
{
byte  TimerSize;         
byte  InterruptLevel;    
} TIMInfo_T;
```

and **tim_api.h** contains the function prototypes of the tim functions

So, the problem is why do I get errors

```
identifier "byte" is undefined
```

When it the first thing I include?

Comment: shouldnt the typedef take care of the error which is included in the first include

Comment: should'nt the typedef in the first include link the two?

Comment: Does `tim.h` also itself include `tim_api.h` at a point before where the `typedef` is? If it's not too long, post the entire `tim.h`, or at least the portion up to and including `TIMInfo_T`.

Comment: If you reduce it to just the `typedef`, the `struct`, and a main program (to print `sizeof(TIMInfo_T)`, say), it works fine, so something else is going on. Does `tim_api.h` have code in it? That sometimes has weird effects.

Comment: tim_api.h just has `extern voids` in it

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the rule that *every* header file should include what it needs to work.

With the setup you have, if someone includes `tim_cfg.h` on its own, the `byte` type is not defined.

A better solution would be:

```
tim_cfg.h:
    #include "tim.h"
    typedef struct
    {
        byte  TimerSize;         
        byte  InterruptLevel;    
    } TIMInfo_T;
```

That way, *everything* that is needed for `tim.cfg.h` is there when you include it.